How to apply break-word in outlook html > table > td > span, specifically to a long url
I have an html table which I send out as email using outlook. The problem I'm having is with long urls that users can input into the td. I'm trying to wrap the url in a span and set that to break-all, but it does not work when I do that.
It only seems to work when I wrap the url in the p element, but this creates both line breaks before and after the url, which i'm not too fond of.
I've read from multiple posts that i can set the span to display:block and it should work, but it does not work for me.
I have also tried to set a width on the span, to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.
<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=577 style="width: 432.75pt; table-layout: fixed;">
          <tr>
             <td><b>Note:</b></td>
             <td>The list of affected servers is here: <p style="word-break: break-all; white-space: wrap; display:inline;">https://reallyreallyreallylongurlherereallyreallyreallylongurlhere</p><br/> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td><b>Published Date:</b></td>
             <td>04/24/2024 03:04 PM</td>
          </tr>
    </table>

